# Bootstrap image responsive grip

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The requirement is that I need to implement some form of the **Bootstrap grid system**. I decided to have responsive images with text description on each image on my page, so when viewing from the desktop the images are side by side and when viewed from mobile the images are stacked including the text.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="container borderColor" >
          <h1 id="example-id-name" class="centered-text sansSerif-text">STOR/E</h1>
           <p class="centered-text"> Every great story begins on a blank page </p> 


           <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-responsive ">
        <img src="images/book1" alt="book one">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-responsive ">
        <img src="images/book2" alt="book two">
    </div>
</div>

My CSS

    .img-responsive{
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: you might want to add an image of the stacking and also mention which bootstrap version(s) (2, 3, 4?) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block

```css
    .img-responsive{
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container borderColor" >
          <h1 id="example-id-name" class="centered-text sansSerif-text">STOR/E</h1>
           <p class="centered-text"> Every great story begins on a blank page </p> 


           <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-responsive ">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kTa0GuA.png" alt="book one">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-responsive ">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kTa0GuA.png" alt="book two">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried this but my images are huge and they are not responsive to the change in size is my initial code wrong

Comment: If your images are too large, depending on their container's size limits there may not be size for them to be side by side. If you run the above code snippet you see the two boxes on top of another since theres not enough space for them to be side by side. If you expand the snippet you see that the boxes are now side by side since there is room. Either shrink the image size or check whats limiting the width they can have (probably their containing div)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use floats or inline-block/block. I plugged in some arbitrary numbers but it's like this:

```
.img-responsive{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 25%;       /* or whatever you want*/
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {   /* or whatever your mobile width is */
    .img-responsive {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this code by expecting that you are using bootsrap
If you are using bootstrap then no need of any css 
Just use this code instead

STOR/E
            Every great story begins on a blank page

```
       <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
    <img class=" img-responsive"  src="images/book1" alt="book one">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <img class=" img-responsive" src="images/book2" alt="book two">
</div>
```

No matter how large your image is, it will display responsive

Answer (score 0):

figured it out thanks for the guidance

```
<div class="container borderColor" >
              <h1 id="example-id-name" class="centered-text sansSerif-text">STOR/E</h1>
               <p class="centered-text"> Every great story begins on a blank page </p> 

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 left "><p class="centered-text">Paper</p><img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/book2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 center"><p class="centered-text">Pens</p><img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/pens"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 right"><p class="centered-text">Covers</p><img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/cover1"></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
```